# uitableview cell accessory type (customized)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

we tried to add a UIButton ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562339/uiimageview-as-a-link-to-a-url)) to a container view (container.addSubView: button), and then assign that container to the accessory view of the cell : (cell.accessoryView = container), but when we open the table view it does not show that accessory view ... why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the frame on the accessory view.